# Best practice for a full width image in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I'm trying to make a featured image 100% width, even if its pixel size is not the width of the screen/body: I'm using the 'full' variable when calling the image via get_the_post_thumbnail but I'm not sure what is the best practice to achieve what I want.

- I can use some JavaScript (it works but I don't know if i like it anymore or if it's the right thing to do)
- I can upload very (2000/2500 px)
  large images, letting scrset manage the smaller sizes. But what if somebody is using a very big screen. And what about the size/quality of the image itself (even if i know how to handle image compression).
- I can remove width and height, along with the sizes=(max-width:pixel) image attribute. This way I can add some CSS rule that let me add some 100% width to the image. But i don't now if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,

I'd recommend you use css:

```
#image{
  width: 100%;
}
```

so set the width to 100% and just omit height, and your picture will be spanned through whole width and the height is going to be in original ratio to width.
About uploading large images, if you do, there will be longer loading times for the website.
Lastly, you can use JavaScript for it if you want.

Comment: Additionally I had to add `height: auto;` in the above code, in order to make my image scaling proportional to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the image a background image of a div (or other block) element, and then apply a background-size property to it. For example:

```
#div-element {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; // Could be anything
    background: ulr('path-to-image') center center no-repeat // there are multiple options for this
    background-size: cover // This stretches the image to fill the div
}
```

This works for me! Hope it does for you.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can set in all images element by using the HTML tag for image:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Remember this will be applied to all  elements, so the image will always be 100% inside the div/element that they are inside.

For any responsive problem what you will encounter you can always use Bootstrap as a reference to solve it.
http://getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0):

if you use `the_post_thumbnail` after translate php code to html code you can access to attribute `srcset` in `img` tag. in `srcset` you can access to other image size. So you can mange image size.

So you can choose use `width: 100%` in `css` or use `srcset`

read this for `srcset`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images